# How can I run a Rails server when I start Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, script, vagrant

I need to run this command

```
cd /my/app/path&&rails s
```

every time I start my Ubuntu virtual machine. I've tried to add it to `/etc/rc.local` file and also in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` but it doesn't work.

I've also tried to run it in an sh script but doesn't work either. Any ideas? I'm using vagrant for virtualizing Ubuntu.

Comment: You shouldn't run Rails like that. The default server and debugging mode is quite slow. If you want Rails to run continuously, you need some decent performance server like Unicorn, then configure an Upstart job (e.g. this https://gist.github.com/errordeveloper/4329034). Also, which Ruby version do you run? Are you using RVM or rbenv? Or the system Ruby? Which user account should the Rails server run as?

Comment: I use rvm and ruby 2.0. I need to run my app in local. Is a small app for handed a small activity. I don't need lot of performance. Should I use another server?

Comment: No, then it's probably fine. But when you redirect the output of that command, e.g. `cd /path && rails s > /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1`, you will see what error prevents the Rails server from starting. Chances are RVM needs to be loaded into your shell. Make sure that if you put that into a script, you launch it as your user, e.g. `sudo -u user bash -c 'cd /path && rails s'` will run as your default user and using Bash, which RVM may need to be loaded (of course, replace `user` with the username that the Rails project runs as).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. If I decide to use an higher performance server witch one should I use?

Comment: I already mentioned that you could use Unicorn. There are quite a few tutorials for Unicorn and Rails on Ubuntu out there. But you will have to diagnose the issue first, as even for Unicorn you need to have it load RVM.

Answer (score 0):

If you have preinstalled ruby rails, then just type

rails s , if you want to change port and access then

rails s -pXXXX , where 'XXXX' stands for the port number you want to run it on

eg. rails s -p8080, where i am running rails server on port 8080

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to set up the server at the specific location where you want(eg, your project).
Then type in the following command home/user/projects/project_name $ rails s.

In case you are unsure about your working directory, type in 'pwd' in the command line from Ubuntu. It stands for 'print working directory' and will give you the current directory where you are pointing to. If you have multiple projects , then go to the parent directory, type in 'ls' in the terminal and it will give you all the child directories that are currently there in the parent directory.